# Sum of first $n$ positive integers to a positive power $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Consider the sum 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{p}\text{ , }p \in \mathbb{Z}^+\text{.}$$
Using a method in Spivak's *Calculus*, it can be shown that
$$(n+1)^{p+1}-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p+1}{k}\left(1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots + n^{k}\right)$$
implying that
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{p} &= \dfrac{\displaystyle(n+1)^{p+1}-1-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{p+1}{k}\left(1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots + n^{k}\right)}{\displaystyle\binom{p+1}{p}} \\
&= \dfrac{\displaystyle(n+1)^{p+1}-1-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{p+1}{k}\left(1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots + n^{k}\right)}{\displaystyle p+1} 
\end{align*}\text{.}$$
Can this expression be simplified any further, in particular, $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{p+1}{k}\left(1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots + n^{k}\right)\text{?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{p+1}{k} m^k
    & = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{p+1}{k} m^k 1^{p+1-k} \\
    & = (m+1)^{p+1} - \sum_{k=p}^{p+1} \binom{p+1}{k} m^k \\
    & = (m+1)^{p+1} - m^{p+1} - (p+1)m^p \\
    & = (m+1)^{p+1} - m^p (m+p+1)
\end{align}

Now you have a straightforward unweighted sum of powers, for $m = 1$ to $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $m +p + 1$ instead, on the last line?

Comment: Bleah, yes, of course.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to *[Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)*
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{p+1}{k}\left(1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots + n^{k}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{p+1}{k} \left( \zeta( -k)-\zeta(-k, n+1) \right)$$
where
$\zeta(s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) and $\zeta(a)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).